# ASP MVC How to deal with TaskCancelledException, extend timeout for PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, task

I'm currently working on a project where I have to make a post request to another API, which takes a significant amount of time (~30-60 seconds) to return. When I make the post request from my controller, I usually (90% of the time) get a TaskCancelledException when the request times out. I've tried using NoAsyncTimeout and AsyncTimeout with a large number but it doesn't seem to be working. The exception happens at the PostAsJsonAsync line of code. The code is below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [NoAsyncTimeout]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(...)
    {
        // processing code

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, data);

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        // processing result
    }
```

Is there anything I should do to increase the timeout time? Or is there another problem with this post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoAsyncTimeout` and `AsyncTimeout` set timeouts for the request that is serviced by this action. It's probable that the POST to `requestUri` is the one that is timing out. Try setting [`HttpClient.Timeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was it!